# Why I am not able to upload media files?

Tags: uploads

I am running a wordpress blog (4.5.3) with no plugins activated, but I am unable to upload any media files. After I click upload, after a while I see Http Error on the screen. In the Firefox net tab, I see request aborted; no response is ever received.

In the apache log, I see

```
[Wed Aug 22 00:26:29.700169 2016] [:error] [pid 20934] [client someip:port] PHP Warning:  
An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server&#8217;s configuration. 
If you continue to have problems, please try the <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/">support forums</a>. 
(WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) 
in /var/www/html/blog/wp-admin/includes/translation-install.php on line 59, 
referer: http://www.somesite.com/blog/wp-admin/media-new.php
```

Comment: What is the size limit for uploading files on your server? and check the permissions for the uploads folder.

Comment: Wordpress shows 2MB and permissions is 777 for 'uploads' folder and user www-data is associated.

Comment: Yes php5-gd and php5-imagick

Comment: Try to upload another image whose size is lessthan 2MB and check whether it's successful.

Comment: I am trying that only; just 18kb size.

Comment: Just a hunch https://wordpress.org/support/topic/http-error-on-image-upload-still?replies=41#post-1222290 May be problem with the image, try uploading another image, check also other solutions provided in that thread.

Comment: Tried different images :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this is your themes function.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

Comment: Please explain how it solves the issue, giving code is not a good solution without any explanation. Thanks for your time.